# Convert .doc/.docx to text with preserving tables

Tags: python, file, text, apache-tika

I want to convert doc/docx files to text files. My requirement is that tables should as it is.

I have tried python tika. It converting the rows to columns

For example table in input doc/docx file

[image]

Above the table is converted to text like below

```
LANGUAGE
UNDERSTAND
LEARN

HINDI
YES
NO

MARATHI
YES
NO

ENGLISH
YES
NO
```

Desired output is like(preserve table format)

```
 LANGUAGE    UNDERSTAND      LEARN  
 HINDI   YES     NO
 MARATHI     YES     NO
 ENGLISH     YES     NO
```

Please let me know if it is possible.

Comment: Did you try pandoc?

Comment: Ask Apache Tika for the HTML rather than plain-text version, then convert tables with your own custom logic, turn the rest into text normally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @ilmiacs suggested `pandoc` can do this for you.
Using `python` you need to install `pypandoc`.
Test document:

[image]

```
import pypandoc
print(pypandoc.convert_file("Untitled 1.docx", "plain+simple_tables", format="docx", extra_args=(), encoding='utf-8', outputfile=None))
```

gives you:

[image]

Clearly, you also have the option of using `subprocess` to bang this onto the command line.